# What's wrong with the following definition of $\lim$ and derivative for the surreal numbers?

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives, surreal-numbers

I am reading about surreal numbers, and was asking myself, what is wrong with the following definition of limit and derivative for surreal functions:
Let $x,p$ are surreal numbers and $f$ is a function from the surreal numbers to itself.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) := \{f(p-\frac{1}{2^k})|f(p+\frac{1}{2^k})\}$$ where $k$ ranges over the natural numbers $1,2,3,\ldots$,  iff the right hand side defines a surreal number.

$$f'(x) := \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta}$$

Is it possbile to prove some properties of the "usual limit" and the "usual derivative"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two immediate issues with your definition:

1. A form must follow the rule that every member of the LHS is smaller than every member of the RHS. This is only ensured if $f$ is increasing.
2. If $f$ is an arbitrary "function" on Surreal numbers (can't be a function since surreal numbers don't form a set), you are only sampling countably many points on either side of $p$, which is not enough to determine the behavior of $f$ around $p$. Since no countable set is dense in the Surreal numbers, this is essentially analogous to asserting that you know $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0} g(t)$ from only knowing $g(-1)$ and $g(1)$ for a real function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, which is absurd.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Would it help for the second point to take $\delta >0 $ instead of $1/2^k$?

Comment: The second definition relies on the first one, and I'm not sure whether there's really a way to rescue the first one. If you get a reasonable definition of a limit of a function, the derivative definition should be reasonable as well.

Comment: Would the countability problem be fixed if the index class was the ordinals?

Comment: @LaveCave taking all surreal $\epsilon> 0$ as in the standard definition of limits should work. That said, I don't believe you'll get standard calculus theorems like the intermediate value theorem or extreme value theorem to hold without some restrictions on your class of "functions".